# Lambda can not insert data into mongodb EC2

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an app working on lambda and api gateway. The database is set in ec2.On the localhost the app is working as expected but when I deploy it to lambda it can not insert data in mongo or even connect to it. We opened all permissions to operate with mongodb and lambda is working on the same vpc as mongo.
Here is my code:

```
MongoClient.connect(dbURL, {useNewUrlParser: true }, function (err, db){

          if (err) {
            console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error: ', err);
          } else {
            console.log('Connection established to ', dbURL);
          }
          let myDB = db.db('iyc')

        let arr = [];

          locations.forEach(element => {
            let insertData = {};
            insertData.user_id = req.body.user_id;
            insertData.device_id = req.body.device_id;
            insertData.app_type = req.body.app_type;
            insertData.datetime = JSON.parse(element.datetime)/1000;
            insertData.latitude = element.latitude;
            insertData.longitude = element.longitude;
            insertData.address = element.address;
            insertData.method = element.method;
            insertData.accuracy = element.accuracy;
            insertData.status = element.status;
            insertData.confidence = element.confidence
           arr.push(insertData)
          }) 

          try {
            myDB.collection('userdevices').insertMany(arr, function(err, data) {
              if(err) {
                console.log("Insert db err " + err)
              } else if(!data) {
                console.log('No data has been inserted')
              }

            })
           }
          catch(err) {
            console.log(err)
          }
          db.close();
       })
```

Comment: Is the port for mongo on ec2 open ? Is local binding off in mongod.conf ?

Comment: the port is open on ec2, but what do you mean by binding off?

Comment: there is bind_ip field in etc/mongod.conf file comment that line or change ip from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0

Comment: won't it cause security issues?

Comment: mongo should have authentication on and if you want to bind it to specific ip then launch lambda in vpc and bind that ip in the mongod.conf file.

Comment: lambda is launched in vpc , but what ip should we bind it

Comment: bind it to CIDR range of the subnet and connect to mongo instance from lambda by ec2's private IP.

Comment: Lambda and Mongo are in the same subnet 
mongodb ip : 172.31.102.145

 and mongod.conf file is :

     `# network interfaces
net:
 port: 27017
 bindIp: 127.0.0.1,172.31.102.145  # Listen to local interface only, comment to listen on all interfaces.`

Comment: and if we set lambda to no vpc(connecting to public ip) it and set binding to this : 

`# network interfaces
net:
 port: 27017
#  bindIp: 127.0.0.1,172.31.102.145  # Listen to local interface only, comment to listen on all interfaces.`

it is working fine. and for security reasons we want lambda to work inside vpc